# how can I fix list function in python

Tags: python, list

I have copied below snipped from Python documentation and executed in my jupyter notebook but
throwing error "list" is not callable

squares = list(map(lambda x: x**2, range(10)))

Comment: Somewhere in your code, you wrote `list = <something>`, which shadowed the builtin `list`.

Comment: You have redefined `list` somewhere earlier.

Comment: Considered this is `resolved` and closed now.  Lesson learned: never redefine the `builtin` `list`  as variable name.